# Bash: tab complete on partial word

Tags: bash, tab-completion, bash-completion

I am very lazy. I am so lazy that I've defined this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  if [ "${1:0:1}" = 'g' ]; then
    git ${1:1} ${@:2}
  else
    #Prevent infinite recursion. Luckily this applies only in this scope.
    unset -f command_not_found_handle
    $@
  fi
}
```

This way, I don't have to type spaces when using git. `gstatus` is equivalent to `git status`, and so on.

Now I want to add tab completion, but as far as I can tell, the `complete` command requires a full word to trigger completion on. Is there any way to trigger completion on patterns or partial words, or would I have to add every possible git command to completion?

Comment: Partial words possible, I think not on patterns. Check out the gitflow completion example here! https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/blob/master/git-flow-completion.bash

Comment: Anything is possible once `complete` has already matched to a completing function, as is the case with git-flow, but for this to work I need to hook into how the initial match is made.

Comment: Why not just declare `gstatus` etc as bash functions? You already know that you can have completions for `gstatus` like commands.

Comment: @anishsane I could enumerate every possible git command as you suggest, but I was hoping there was a more elegant method.